# a number is produced at random time interval

Tags: random

I am really new in Programming and I can hardly understand them. I have to do this question where a customer will come to the counter to buy tickets. I have to do coding where a customer will come at a random time. I don't know how to do the coding for it. Till now I only managed to come up with the random number of customers and the timer. But I don't know how to write the coding where it can tell you at 'this' second a customer has come to buy the ticket. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: It might help your question's quality if you add a tag for the programming language you want to use. Also, are you trying to generate a random time, or do you want to know the time the customer buys the ticket?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "I don't know how to do the coding for it." – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a specific, focused, narrow question on [so].

Comment: When a customer arrive at the cinema, he/she will go to the queue. If the customer is a VIP member, he/she will go to the priority queue, or else if he/she is a non-member, he/she will go to the normal queue. VIP member customer must be served before any non-member customer. Whenever there are customers waiting in the queue, the available service counters has to call the next customer and serve them. There should not be any idle service counter except there is no more customer to serve.   - this is my question and i am doing it in java, i have to know the arrival time of the customer

Comment: "this is my question and i am doing it in java, i have to know the arrival time of the customer" – Then you write a program in Java which computes the arrival time of the customer. If you have a problem with your program, then you read and re-read all the documentation for all the libraries, classes, and methods you use, write tests for your code, debug your code, have your code be reviewed by your friends and colleagues, and if you still haven't figured out the problem, you narrow your problem down to a concise, simple, short, small, focused, specific, narrow, reproducible [mcve] and ask [so]

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what programming language you are using, but the timers in most languages will call some function when the timer is up. You can define this function however you want to tell you when the customer has come.